# Show a custom calendar dropdown with a derived DateTimePicker class

Tags: c#, winapi, datetimepicker

My goal is to create a custom DateTimePicker class in .NET 2.0, which shows a custom calendar dropdown instead of the Windows default calendar popup.

By observing Windows messages (see attached code), I am able to find and hide/close the calendar window after creation.

However, a problem remains: After the calendar window is closed, something is still blocking the mouse input. For example, if you try to maximise the owner form of the customised DateTimePicker control after the calendar dropdown has been closed programmatically (attached code), the maximise button does not respond. Only the next click works. Interestingly, the "non-functional click" fires the DTN_CLOSEUP notification, so it appears that the WM_CLOSE did not properly close the calendar.

Any hints on how to accomplish my task are highly appreciated :)

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == (int)SYSMSG.WM_REFLECT + (int)SYSMSG.WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        NMHDR nmhdr = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
        switch (nmhdr.code)
        {
            case DTN_DROPDOWN:
                // Hide window
                IntPtr calHandle = FindWindow("SysMonthCal32", null);
                SendMessage(calHandle, (int)SYSMSG.WM_SIZE, 0, SP.Convert.MakeLong(0, 0));

                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    SendMessage(calHandle, (int)SYSMSG.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                });
                break;
        }

    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Hi, where can I find the actual message code for `DTN_DROPDOWN`? Scoured the web but they only mention the name not the code. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind my question got answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587540/where-can-i-get-the-actual-message-codes-for-the-winform-datetimepicker-control

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending a `WM_CLOSE` have you tried sending a `DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL` message instead? You would send this to the HWND of the DateTimePicker itself and not the child window.  According to the documentation, the [DateTime_CloseMonthCal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761784(VS.85).aspx) macro sends this message and it seems like what you want to do.

I also don't think you'll need to use BeginInvoke to send it unless there's some problem with closing it in the same dispatch as a drop down notification.

```
#define DTM_FIRST        0x1000
#define DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL (DTM_FIRST + 13)
#define DateTime_CloseMonthCal(hdp) SNDMSG(hdp, DTM_CLOSEMONTHCAL, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the message closes the calendar properly. However, the problem with the mouse capture remains, and "this.Capture=false" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this fully customisable datePicker (monthCalendar rendering is override-able) : [Culture Aware Month Calendar and Datepicker on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/CultureMonthCalendar.aspx)