# OwnerDraw DateTime Picker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, ownerdrawn

I'd like to use a MonthPicker instead of a DateTimePicker, that will have exactly the same implementation as the DateTimePicker except for the dropdown panel that would only show months and year selection (instead of days, months and year) - I cannot post any image as a newbee here, though I made one :(

Is there any way to override DateTimePicker rendering (ownerdraw kinda stuff) or what would be the best way to reproduce the DateTimePicker behavior if this is not possible ?

Comment: Use a dropdown with months :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Showupdown will disable the dropdown showing the calender, if you are interested only in month and year set `CustomFormat = "mm/yyyy"`

Comment: Nope, I want the Dropdown allowed but only showing Months instead of days. i have just found a fully cusomizable Monthcalendar on codeProject http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/monthcalendar.aspx that will replace perfectly the dateTimePicker Monthcalendar Dropdown, but how to do this ? (DateTimePicker embeded monthCalendar is hidden at code level)... I guess that by overriding DateTimePicker and/or catching OnDropDown event I could Display this new extended MonthCalendar instead of the real one ?

Comment: This is a control so you could use it after customizing by referencing the control in your app

Comment: Don't you think I could substitute this new Calendar to the default DateTimePicker one ? (I can't find the corresponding object with the debugger, no childs, no components, nothing, this is weird)...

Answer (score 0):

For information, I found another discussion on the same subject here :
[Show a custom calendar dropdown with a derived DateTimePicker class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137997/show-a-custom-calendar-dropdown-with-a-derived-datetimepicker-class/5665930#5665930)