# How can I remove the "Today" button from DateTimePicker control (of Windows form Control)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

In the DateTimePicker control, when we click the dropdown button , a calendar gets displayed . at the bottom of the calendar , there is a button : Today , which on being clicked , sets the present date as the selected date.
I want to remove/hide that button from the control. How can I do it?

Comment: In WPF it is possible. In Winforms i am not sure.

Comment: After some searching around, I don't think it's possible in Winforms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The native Windows DateTimePicker control supports the DTM_SETMCSTYLE message to set the style of the month calender.  You just need a little pinvoke to send the message when the control is created and change the default style.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the old one.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker {
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        int style = (int)SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        style |= MCS_NOTODAY | MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)style);
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
    //pinvoke:
    private const int DTM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int DTM_SETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 11;
    private const int DTM_GETMCSTYLE = DTM_FIRST + 12;
    private const int MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE = 0x0008;
    private const int MCS_NOTODAY = 0x0010;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

It looks like this at runtime, on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: in the solution u have inherited the dateTimePicker control, but how to accomplish the above task without using inheritance ?

Comment: well for the above  - no inheritance thing ....
we can just have to  use  :
this.dtp1.handle //dtp1 is an object of dateTimePicker.

Comment: your answer was perfect, worked for Windows 7 but not on windows XP. can u plz tell how can it work for windows XP ??

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall wanting to modify this control myself a while ago, and finding out that it is not possible.  The solution was to build your own custom control.

If it helps, I did find this [Show a custom calendar dropdown with a derived DateTimePicker class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137997/show-a-custom-calendar-dropdown-with-a-derived-datetimepicker-class), which links to a custom Winforms calendar [Culture Aware Month Calendar and DatePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45684/Culture-Aware-Month-Calendar-and-Datepicker).