# Winforms: Remove "Today" from DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, custom-controls

I'm trying to remove the Today link shown at the bottom of the datetimepicker control.
I found a similar question with code but this does not appear to work - Is there an issue with my conversion or is this method no longer valid (Visual Studio 2012)?

```
Class MyDateTimePicker
Inherits DateTimePicker
Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
    Dim style As Integer = CInt(SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_GETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
    style = style Or MCS_NOTODAY Or MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE
    SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, CType(0, IntPtr))
    MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
End Sub

Private Const DTM_FIRST As Integer = &H1000
Private Const DTM_SETMCSTYLE As Integer = DTM_FIRST + 11
Private Const DTM_GETMCSTYLE As Integer = DTM_FIRST + 12
Private Const MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE As Integer = &H8
Private Const MCS_NOTODAY As Integer = &H10

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wp As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
End Class
```

Source: [How can I remove the "Today" button from DateTimePicker control (of Windows form Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918138/how-can-i-remove-the-today-button-from-datetimepicker-control-of-windows-form)

Comment: No, that still works fine in VS2012 and Win8.  You didn't copy the code correctly however.  Use CType(style, IntPtr), not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the style:

Change this:

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, CType(0, IntPtr))
```

to this:

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, DTM_SETMCSTYLE, IntPtr.Zero, CType(style, IntPtr))
```