# Modify "Today" in DateTimePicker control in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

The date in "Today" is set to system date by default. I have a requirement in the application where I want to change today to some specific date different from default. Any idea how can this be changed in DateTimePicker control in Winforms?
[image]

Comment: How does it make sense? Today should be today's date.

Comment: @danish Maybe it's related to time travel :)

Comment: You can't change the meaning of "today".  All you can do is [remove it today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921472/17034).

Comment: @danish maybe he will change the word today to an event name, and the date should show that event's date

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani That's different and an assumption as of now. OP has not mentioned that. He wants to change date shown after Today.

Comment: Hi, In my scenario Today is different from System Date. It's coming from an external component and it may be different from current/system date.

Comment: Just for some clarification, In my domain (financial) mostly Today is referred to TradeDate. So, I would like to initialize accordingly. And yes, it's got nothing to with time travel :) . Didn't like people downvoting the question.