# Where can I get the actual message codes for the Winform DateTimePicker control?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, wndproc

I am building a custom datetimepicker control derived from the standard datetimepicker control and I need to deal with it's messages in the WndProc override.

I have scoured the web but the following links are as best as I can get:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485908(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485909(v=vs.85).aspx

They don't provide the actual message values.

Appreciate your kind help.

Thanks in advance.

**By the way**

I'm using VS 2015 Community

Comment: Use the commctrl.h SDK header, search for DTM_FIRST.  You did not mention you VS version, important.  Most everybody has it in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include directory.

Comment: Or take a look at [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NativeMethods.cs,441)

Comment: Don't use the reference source, it is not complete.  It only has the message numbers of the ones that the DateTimePicker wrapper class actually uses.  In which case there's no point in asking the question, you'd just use DTP.